# oracle database with 2 different accessing parties

Tags: oracle, jpa, jboss

We have the following setting:
There is a web application which has a jboss 6 as a backend.
There is an oracle database (11 g).
There is one table with the name "changes".
A stateless session bean in the jboss is ONLY READING from this "changes" table via JPA (eclipselink, entity manager).
The data for the changes table come from a different source:
A C program on a different server connects to the aforementioned oracle 11g database via OCI interface (no jboss!) and either creates new rows or updates rows in the "changes" database.
Has somebody experience with this kind of things?
Is it generally discouraged to act from an other source while jboss/jpa is working with a database.
Thanks a lot in advance for your information
Wolfgang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the database is concerned, this should be all fine, actually this is exactly what an RDBMS for. Check out [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

As a note on performance, your Web Applicaton won't be effected dramatically with the inserts and updates (if there are no design issues) since Oracle reads do not wait for writes. Check out the concept of [Multi-Versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control).